# IllegalArgument exception No view found

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception

This is the error im getting:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09003d (com.company.app:id/container) for fragment friendFragment{118ad082 #0 id=0x7f09003d}`

I did some debugging and found that the error was coming from this line:

`transaction.replace(R.id.container, friendFragment).commit();`

Within my layout xml file, I have created a fragment which is called `R.id.container`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

The OnCreate code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //TODO Add Fragment to activity using getSupportFragmentManager() method

    FriendFragment friendFragment= new FriendFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.container, friendFragment).commit();                  //This line
```

With my Fragment class:

```
   public static class FriendFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_frag_main, "friend_fragment");

    }

}
```

I'd love some help on how I can fix this because I don't know why its happening?

Any help, answers or suggestions would be great!

**UPDATE:** 
Thanks to @MikeM, I solved this issue. See solution below in comments!

Comment: The `R.id` you pass in that `replace()` call is for the `ViewGroup` in the `Activity`'s layout – e.g., often a `<FrameLayout>` – that the `Fragment`'s `View` will be added to, not anything in the `Fragment`'s layout.

Comment: @MikeM, thanks for the suggestion! So just to clarify, I need to add a layout file for the fragment and return Inflator to inflate the layout of the fragment?

Comment: No, a `PreferenceFragment` builds its own layout from your preference XML, so you don't need a layout for that `Fragment` at all. You just need some `ViewGroup` in the `Activity` for it to be placed into; as mentioned, often an empty `<FrameLayout>`.

Comment: Also, for future reference, a `<fragment>` element in a layout is not just a placeholder in an `Activity` for a dynamically transacted `Fragment`, nor is it meant to be in the `Fragment`'s own layout. I'm not sure what yours was intended for, but it actually causes a separate `Fragment` instance to be created and added when the layout is inflated. Yours should crash, though, if it were to ever be used, since there's no `class` or `android:name` attribute on it that points to a `Fragment` class.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. Thanks again for more help, but I’m not sure I understand. Are you saying I should wrap the <Fragment> inside a <framelayout> and then pass the <framelayout> Id in .replace method? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: No, if you're handling creating and transacting that `Fragment` yourself, get rid of the  `<fragment>` altogether. You just need a `<FrameLayout>` in the `Activity`'s layout to put that `Fragment` into. That `<FrameLayout>`'s `R.id` is then what you would pass as the first argument in the `replace()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. Gave that a try, but for some reason, still seem to get the same error :( Thank you though!

Comment: The `<FrameLayout>` goes in the `activity_main` layout. Set `android:id="@+id/container"` on it. As long as you've got only one `activity_main` layout, the code you've posted in the first snippet has to work, or, at least, it has to be a different Exception. If it doesn't work, and your certain that the _current_ Exception is still the same, then try cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: @MikeM. Yep! Wasn’t syncing properly! Thanks so much, you solved my problem. Really appreciate it :)